# Index Match - return values and exclude all values previously returned

Tags: excel

Hi i am currently trying to set up a formula in excel where i have on sheet one some information e.g. ID and then the country of each ID

what i want to do is an index match style formula where on sheet 2, there will be a cell saying 'England'

then the formula will look in sheet one, scan column B and look for England and return the ID. However my problem with index match is it only returns the first in the list, what i need to do is return the ID and then check again excluding the cells above.

I cant seem to get it to work, ideally it would look like the below

Sheet 1

```
A              B
ID          Country
1           England
2            Wales
3           England
4           Scotland
5           Wales
```

Sheet 2: England

```
A              
ID         
1           
3
```

EDIT: I'm looking to do it purely from a formula, no VBA code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=index('sheet one'!a:a, aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$999)/('sheet one'!b$2:b$999="england"), row(1:1)))
```

That gets you the first. Fill down and row(1:1) becomes row(2:2), row(3:3) for the second, third, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Power Query** (Get & Transform Data):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Country] = "England"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

You could use a **Pivot Table**:

Put fields `ID` and `Country` in `ROWS`. Choose report layout `Tabular`. Switch `Subtotals` and `Grand Totals` off. Filter `Country` = England.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA procedure will be able to handle it.

> Under presumption the original data is stored in a table called `Table1`

```
Private Sub find_occurance(ByVal Country As String)
    Dim next_free_row As Long

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
        If Trim(LCase(Cell.Value2)) = Trim(LCase(Country)) Then
            next_free_row = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(next_free_row, "A") = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(next_free_row, "B") = Cell.Value2
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

So for example, if in Sheet2, you created a the following button, with this code

```
Private Sub Command_Button1_Click()
    Dim Checked_Country As String
    Checked_Country = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Value2

    Call find_occurance(Checked_Country)

End Sub
```

You could have it look like this, so whenever the user would press a button, it would list all the IDs.

[image]